# I try to save progress with code in my Unity Game but I have problems with it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I try to save progress with code but I have problems with it. I try 5 ways but It always gives an error.Thanks.

I have trouble with this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Settings
{
    public enum Languages
    {
        English,
        Turkce
    }

    public struct Save
    {
        public int save_point;
        public int percent;
    }


    public Languages lang;

    public Save save1;
    public Save save2;
    public Save save3;

    public static Settings data = new Settings();
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public class Settings_Issues : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool _out;
    public int _out_type;
    public int _out_id;
    void Start()
    {
       if(_out)
       {
            if (_out_type == 0)
            {

                if (_out_id == 0) GetComponent<Text>().text = "%" + Settings.data.save1.percent.ToString();
                if (_out_id == 1) GetComponent<Text>().text = "%" + Settings.data.save2.percent.ToString();
                if (_out_id == 2) GetComponent<Text>().text = "%" + Settings.data.save3.percent.ToString();

            }
        } 
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public static void Load()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Save.gsd";
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        Settings data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as Settings;
        stream.Close();

        Settings.data= data;

    }


    public static void Save()
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Save.gsd";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, Settings.data);
        stream.Close();

        Debug.Log(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Save.gsd");
    }
}
```

It gives this error when I use Save() with a button:

`SerializationException: Type 'Settings+Save' in Assembly 'Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.`

The full error is :

```
SerializationException: Type 'Settings+Save' in Assembly 'Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers (System.RuntimeType type) (at <e40e5a8f982c4b618a930d29f9bd091c>:0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices+<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<GetSerializableMembers>b__0 (System.Runtime.Serialization.MemberHolder _) (at <e40e5a8f982c4b618a930d29f9bd091c>:0)
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue].GetOrAdd (TKey key, System.Func`2[T,TResult] valueFactory) (at <e40e5a8f982c4b618a930d29f9bd091c>:0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers (System.Type type, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context) (at <e40e5a8f982c4b618a930d29f9bd091c>:0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo () (at <e40e5a8f982c4b618a930d29f9bd091c>:0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize (System.Object obj, System.Runtime.Serialization.ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatterConverter converter, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter objectWriter, System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder binder) (at <e40e5a8f982c4b618a930d29f9bd091c>:0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize (System.Object obj, System.Runtime.Serialization.ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatterConverter converter, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter objectWriter, System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder binder) (at <e40e5a8f982c4b618a930d29f9bd091c>:0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write (System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.NameInfo memberNameInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.NameInfo typeNameInfo) (at <e40e5a8f982c4b618a930d29f9bd091c>:0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize (System.Object graph, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[] inHeaders, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryWriter serWriter, System.Boolean fCheck) (at <e40e5a8f982c4b618a930d29f9bd091c>:0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Object graph, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[] headers, System.Boolean fCheck) (at <e40e5a8f982c4b618a930d29f9bd091c>:0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Object graph, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[] headers) (at <e40e5a8f982c4b618a930d29f9bd091c>:0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Object graph) (at <e40e5a8f982c4b618a930d29f9bd091c>:0)
Settings_Issues.Save () (at Assets/Scripts/Settings_Issues.cs:61)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () (at <4a31731933e0419ca5a995305014ad37>:0)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at <4a31731933e0419ca5a995305014ad37>:0)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:70)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:114)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:57)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:272)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update() (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:501)
```

Comment: Did you try reading the error message?

Comment: Please do not use BinaryFormatter, it is slow, fragile, insecure, and obsoleted in newer versions of .Net. It is no fun updating .net version and discovering that all your saved data can no longer be read. If you do not know what to use, use Json. I believe that unity has builtin Json support. There are also libraries for binary serialization (like protobuf .net) if you prioritize speed and size over readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Settings` class is marked as serializable, but the nested struct `Save` isn't. To be able to serialize `Settings`, `Save` also needs to be marked as serializable. i.e:

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public struct Save
{
    public int save_point;
    public int percent;
}
```